# No exception or error still not inserting values in the table

Tags: java, mysql

```
public void saveNewParam(Connection conn, GlobalParamDTO globalParamDTO) throws SLCMException {

    SLCMLog.info("Enter saveNewParam()");
    PreparedStatement pstmt = null;
    String query = SLCMQueryConstant.INSERT_GLOBAL_PARAM;
    try {

        int count = 1;
        pstmt = conn.prepareStatement(query);
        pstmt.setInt (count++, globalParamDTO.getParamTypeID());
        pstmt.setString(count++, globalParamDTO.getParamValue());
        pstmt.setString(count++, globalParamDTO.getParamValueHindi());
        System.out.println(globalParamDTO.getParamValueHindi());
        pstmt.executeUpdate();

    } catch (Exception e) {
        throw new SLCMException(e.getMessage());
    } finally {
        ConnectionManager.close(null, null, null, pstmt);
    }
}
```

No exception or error still not inserting values in the table 
 query-

```
public static final String INSERT_GLOBAL_PARAM = new StringBuilder("").
        append(" INSERT INTO m_global_param (Param_Type_ID,Value,Value_Hindi) ").
        append(" VALUES(?,?,?)").toString();
```

Comment: Check if auto commit is false for the connection.

Comment: Auto increment is True for this table. and column as Param_ID is entertain for auto increment.

Comment: Auto commit as in JDBC autocommit. You can verify if the data is inserted by running select query immediately after the insertion in your code, if you're getting the data in the select query then it can only mean that auto commit for your connection is false and you have to manually commit the connection by calling `connection.commit()` at the end.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
System.out.println(conn.getAutoCommit());
```

If the above line prints false then you have to explicitly call commit() in order to commit changes.

```
conn.commit();
```

By default a connection object has auto-commit set to true, if you setting `conn.setAutoCommit(false)` somewhere in your code, then you have to commit explicitly.